# Can i show the weather condition in my android app, when Internet is not available

Tags: android

I want to show weather condition and temperature of user current location in my android app, when Internet is not available on his location, is this possible?
if yes, then how?

Comment: Weather would rather require internet to fetch details from respective servers. But for temperature, if you have an external device which measures temperature, you can communicate with that device (via Bluetooth, NFC, local network wifi, etc, depends upon type of device) and get current temperature. Rather mobile device does not have temperature sensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to get weather conditions without internet connection.
You can get current temperature if the phone has [AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE sensor](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_environment).
If you want to see AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE sensor in action, or just want to see how to use it, I'd suggest you to see [this link](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-create-a-thermometer-application-for-android-295d6611b4f9).